# How Number of commutator segments,air gap between the segments of brush dc motor affect on performance of DC motor..?

Tags: motor, dc, waveform

plese help me about how Number of commutator segments,air gap between the commutator segments of brush dc motor affect on performance of DC motor..??

now if we we change the number of commutator segments 5,7,9,11 then how air gap between collectors should changes and how it affect on performance of dc motor i:e affect on waveform and torque ripple of dc motor..??

Answer (score 1):

more segments implies more magnetic pole-pieces on the rotor, more pole-pieces implies smoother torque at a given speed.

gap between the poles must be sufficient to extinguish the arc that forms when the brush leaves.  more poles means a smaller voltage difference between segments so a smaller gap can be used.

Comment: thnks jasen i just wants know tht what will be the effect if only two magnetic poles are there but no.of collector segments changed.(consider miniature coreless brush DC motor)

Comment: the number of segments is always the same as the number of pole pieces on the rotor.  the stator usually has 2 poles and 2 brushes, but some tines has 4 poles and 4 brushes, when operating the cueenr through the rotoe windings will magnetise the pole-pieces in groups, forming the same number of magnetic poles as there are brushes

Comment: thnks jasen..can i have your contact (gmail,facebook) plz..?

Answer (score 0):

The number of commutator segments is NOT equal to the number of poles! A 2-pole motor can have several pairs of commutator segments. The more pairs the closer together and the smoother the motor runs. This may also have an impact on torque as the overlapping sine waves of neighboring commutator pairs is additive. Of course, more current will also be flowing in this case. You don't get power or torque for free!